# how to attach a document to a GUI java program?

Tags: java, swing, file, user-interface, attachment

so basically imagine a program that is stored within a .jar file(so a pure java program) that stores and organizes PDF/doc/image files that contain scans of forms for patients at a hospital. how would one go about attaching documents to this program?

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by "attaching documents"?

Comment: The .jar file can contain non-code resources. How is your jar being built? `jar -cvf`? Via Ant or Maven?